# call application libjingle, user automatically removed from roster. why?

Tags: c++, p2p, voip, libjingle

Okay, Tried running the compiled "call" program in libjingle-0.6.14, on 2 laptops with ubuntu 11.10,

When i log in from the first laptop, and logged in again (with different account) from the other lappy.. The user coming online is immediately removed from roster and im left with no one to call...

Here is the Output..

```
   <stream:stream from="gmail.com" id="1D65B8B570251398" version="1.0"xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
 XmppLoginTask::Advance - LOGINSTATE_STREAMSTART_SENT
 RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Tue Aug 21 18:37:51 2012
  <stream:features>
 <mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
   <mechanism>
     PLAIN
   </mechanism>
   <mechanism>
     X-GOOGLE-TOKEN
   </mechanism>
   <mechanism>
     X-OAUTH2
   </mechanism>
 </mechanisms>
</stream:features>
XmppLoginTask::Advance - LOGINSTATE_STARTED_XMPP
XmppLoginTask::Advance - LOGINSTATE_AUTH_INIT
XmppLoginTask::Advance - LOGINSTATE_SASL_RUNNING
SEND >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : Tue Aug 21 18:37:51 2012


 <auth xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" mechanism="PLAIN" auth:allow-
 non-google- 
  login="true" auth:client-uses-full-bind-result="true" 
 xmlns:auth="http://www.google.com/talk/protocol/auth">
 ## TEXT REMOVED ##
 </auth>
 RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Tue Aug 21 18:37:51 2012
<success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"/>
XmppLoginTask::Advance - LOGINSTATE_SASL_RUNNING
XmppLoginTask::Advance - No error
XmppLoginTask::Advance - LOGINSTATE_STREAMSTART_SENT
SEND >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : Tue Aug 21 18:37:51 2012
<stream:stream to="gmail.com" xml:lang="*" version="1.0" 
xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Tue Aug 21 18:37:51 2012
<stream:stream from="gmail.com" id="2B727FCA62E71E0F" version="1.0" 
xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
XmppLoginTask::Advance - LOGINSTATE_STREAMSTART_SENT
RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Tue Aug 21 18:37:51 2012
<stream:features>
 <bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/>
 <session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/>
 </stream:features>
XmppLoginTask::Advance - LOGINSTATE_STARTED_XMPP
XmppLoginTask::Advance - LOGINSTATE_BIND_INIT
XmppLoginTask::Advance - LOGINSTATE_BIND_REQUESTED
SEND >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : Tue Aug 21 18:37:51 2012


<iq type="set" id="0">
 <bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind">
   <resource>
     call
   </resource>
 </bind>
 </iq>
RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Tue Aug 21 18:37:51 2012
<iq id="0" type="result">
  <bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind">
   <jid>
     tejeshsmith@gmail.com/call6183138F
   </jid>
  </bind>
</iq>
XmppLoginTask::Advance - LOGINSTATE_BIND_REQUESTED
XmppLoginTask::Advance - LOGINSTATE_SESSION_REQUESTED
SEND >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : Tue Aug 21 18:37:51 2012
<iq type="set" id="1">
 <session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/>
</iq>
RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Tue Aug 21 18:37:51 2012
RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Tue Aug 21 18:37:51 2012

<iq type="result" id="1"/>
XmppLoginTask::Advance - LOGINSTATE_SESSION_REQUESTED
logged in...
Creating default VideoCapturer
Enumerating V4L2 devices
V4L2 device metadata found at /sys/class/video4linux/
Found V4L2 capture device /dev/video0
Trying /sys/class/video4linux/video0/name
Name for video0 is HP Webcam
Total V4L2 devices found : 1
Creating default VideoCapturer
Enumerating V4L2 devices
V4L2 device metadata found at /sys/class/video4linux/
Found V4L2 capture device /dev/video0
Trying /sys/class/video4linux/video0/name
Name for video0 is HP Webcam 
Total V4L2 devices found : 1
Selected PulseAudio sound system
Number of references: 1
<pre><code>Number of references: 0
Selected PulseAudio sound system
Number of references: 1
Number of references: 0
Enumerating V4L2 devices
V4L2 device metadata found at /sys/class/video4linux/
Found V4L2 capture device /dev/video0
Trying /sys/class/video4linux/video0/name
Name for video0 is HP Webcam
Total V4L2 devices found : 1
SEND >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> : Tue Aug 21 18:37:51 2012
<presence>
 <status/>
 <priority>
   0
 </priority>
 <c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" node="http://code.google.com/p/libjingle
 /call" ver="0.6" ext=" pmuc-v1"/>
 <x xmlns="jabber:x:delay" stamp="20120821T13:07:51"/>
</presence>
RECV <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< : Tue Aug 21 18:37:52 2012
<presence from="smithtejesh@gmail.com/callAB04C4D8"  
to="tejeshsmith@gmail.com/call6183138F">
 <status/>
 <priority>
   0
 </priority>
 <c node="http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/call" ver="0.6" ext=" pmuc-v1" 
 xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps"/>
 <x stamp="20120821T12:58:59" xmlns="jabber:x:delay"/>
 <x xmlns="vcard-temp:x:update"/>
```

Removing from roster: smithtejesh@gmail.com/callAB04C4D8

smithtejesh@gmail.com is REMOVED from roster..automatically... what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that the arguments for calling the "call" example are incomplete. The example, without modification, that ships with the libjingle source does not capture video/audio from the computer's hardware. It will play rtp dump files that contain audio/video. The source files do come with sample rtp dump files that can be used to play audio/video to a browser client, or can be "transfered" to another "call" example client and saved locally to a rtcp dump file on the second client.

The proper way to use the call example program is along the lines of (if on linux):

```
./call --videoinput ./test.rtpdump --voiceinput ./voice.rtpdump --videooutput ./vidoutput.rtpdump --voiceoutput ./voioutput.rtpdump
```

There are a few issues on the libjingle Google code website that talk about this, I am struggling to find them at the moment. If I do, I will edit this post or add a comment with the links.

Comment: yeah.. and the latest version of the "call" program removes you from the roster if you do not show video and voice capability in the "caps" section of xmpp. And by using the linphonemediaengine instead of filemediaengine, you can hear audio real-time rather than just read from the dump files..